# Django: How do I create a new model containing all the fields of another model (but unrelated to it)?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, model

Given an existing Django model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...
    ...
    fieldN = ...
```

I would like to create a wholly separate model that looks like this:

```
class MyModel2(models.Model):
    field1 = ...
    field2 = ...
    ...
    fieldN = ...

    fieldA = ...
    fieldB = ...
    ...
    fieldZ = ...
```

Multi-table inheritance does not work for me as I want MyModel2 to be backed by a database table containing all of its fields, not just the extra ones plus a link to the MyModel table.

Defining an Abstract Base Class might work if I could change the definition of MyModel. But is there another way, possibly using the Python `type` metaclass?

Comment: I would use an Abstract Base Class. Metaclass magic is too clever for this.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes check this

Answer (score 1):

Why not an abstract base class for both, and one of your concrete classes has no further fields?

Comment: Because in general I may not be able to change the definition of MyModel. So essentially I'm looking for a function that, given the original unchanged MyModel, returns MyModel2.

Comment: @jl6: I suggest you read about Django models, then play around with them, and try to implement that, then come back with any specific questions you have. Examine the `_meta` attribute of your models - there's a wealth of stuff in there.